# Visa cancellation

Tags: australia, south-african-citizens

I was in Australia in 1999 on a visitors Visa. I took on a job and was found out by the authorities that I was working and my Visa was cancelled and I was asked to leave (not deported) I subsequently left within 7 days and purchased my own ticket. Does this mean I can never return  to Australia?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.

You should have been informed about any exclusion period (‘re-entry ban’) applied to you when your visa was cancelled. If you don’t know this information, you should contact the staff at your nearest immigration office.

You can still apply for a permanent visa if you have been banned from re-entering Australia. Your immigration history will be considered when the Department of Home Affairs makes a decision on your application.

For temporary visa applications you can ask the Department of Home Affairs to set aside a ban.

https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/entering-australia/can-i-go-to-australia

Comment: Do we know whether OP even has a ban?

Comment: @phoog No we don’t, my answer wasn’t intended to imply that the OP is banned, just to state the position if they were/are. I’ll amend it.